# How to use XSD that includes another XSD with JAXB while XSDs reside in JAR?

Tags: java, xml, jar, xsd, jaxb

I am reading XML files that are validated via XSD files into XJC generated classes. That all works fine when I reference the XSD in the normal file system. Now I want to bundle the XSD into my JAR. That also works fine as long the XSD is standalone with the following code:

```
//Use the schema factory to get the schema
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

//Get XSD from JAR
InputStream schemaStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/schema/myschema.xsd");
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(schemaStream));

//parse the XML file and fill the data model
Class<T> c = getXmlDataModelClass();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);

m_JaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

//set the schema to be considered
m_JaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

return (T)m_JaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Now the problem: if myschema.xsd includes another XSD:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="BaseTypes.xsd"/>
```

The types in the included XSD are not found.

I also tried to pass an array of two `StreamSource` with both XSDs into `sf.newSchema()`, but that did not help.

Comment: Solved at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771208/organizing-xsds-in-a-jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771208/organizing-xsds-in-a-jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to use URLs, something like (not tested):

```
URL schemaURL = getClass().getResource("/schema/myschema.xsd");
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaURL);
```

You'll get a `jar:...` URL and feed it to the schema factory. As long as included schemas reside in the same JAR, they should be resolved without problems.

For more advanced usage you may instantiate and provide a resource resolver to the schema factory:

```
sf.setResourceResolver(myResourceResolver);
```

The resource resolver resolves schemas into resources. You can use something like `XMLCatalogResolver` to rewrite schema URLs using catalog files, for instance. This would allow you to rewrite absolute URLs into local resources.